# How to filter out specific characters using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, data-cleaning

I need to regex to filter out specific characters from strings in my dataset. How can I filter out the numerical digits and the "-" symbol when it is between the numbers, and skip over the "-" symbol when it is between alphabetical characters, cause the regular expression that I use now filters out every "-" symbol between any alphanumeric character in addition to when it is between numeric characters.

Example:

Problem: "Non-Profit Organization management, 100-200 employees"
Current outcome: "NonProfit Organization management, employees"
Desired outcome: "Non-Profit Organization management, employees"

```
if 'business' in row.keys():
            row['business'] = re.sub("[0-9-][0-9]*", '', str(row['business']))
```

Comment: in R? or Python?

Comment: I'm doing it in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the expression `\d+-\d+` in order to replace all - including digits (\d) with empty strings.

```py
print(re.sub("\d+-\d+ *", "", "Non-Profit Organization management, 100-200 employees"))
```

Results in "Non-Profit Organization management, employees"

**Note** that I added  `*` to the pattern in order to remove spaces after the number, too.

**Suggestion**:
If you perform this operation several times, I would suggest you to do as follows:

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile("\d+-\d+ *")
print(pattern.sub("", "Non-Profit Organization management, 100-200 employees"))
```

So Python doesn't need to compile the pattern every time.

Comment: @tahakhawaja Please mark any of the answers as solved if it helped you :D –

Comment: how can I change this regular expression to also remove numbers that consist of comma symbols in the number such as "500-10,000" or with a comma and a + symbol such as this one: "10,000+"

Comment: `\d[\d,]*-\d[\d,]* *`

Comment: Can you please tell me how I could do that exact same thing, except instead of matching for it, it matches everything except anything included in this pattern? Example: \d[\d,]*-\d[\d,]* * or Example: \d+-\d+ *

Comment: you can use [^PATTERN] in order to negate a pattern, so `[^\d]`

Comment: I tried to do it this way, but it does not seem to work. [^\d[\d,]*-\d[\d,]* *] am I missing something or is the pattern wrong anywhere?

Comment: give me in&output so I can write a fitting pattern

Comment: EXAMPLE 1: ("Input: Health, Wellness and Fitness , 100-500 employees", "Output: 100-500" ) EXAMPLE 2: ("Input: Retail, 10,000+ employees", "Output: 10,000+") and for any of these examples, if the cell contains "Self-employed" I need to keep the "Self-employed" as is untouched in the output (Self-employed is usually on its own without anything else).

Comment: That's the code: https://nekobin.com/caharudaqa.py
As you can see it didn't fail in any `assert` so it means everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
string = "Non-Profit Organization management, 100-200 employees"
re.sub("(\d+)-(\d+)", "", string)
```

Output:

```
'Non-Profit Organization management,  employees'
```